# select random users sql

Tags: sql, select, random

In one of my tables I have a listing of purchases by userID, date, products, channels, etc.  I'd like to select a random set of users so I can run a sample analysis.  If I use rand(), I will have the chance of excluding a user's 2nd, 3rd, nth purchase with us.  What's the best way to grab 50, 100, 60000 random users and see all of their purchases?

```
select userID,
date,
SKU,
Campaign,
Device

where date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-31'

from Sales
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select a top(X) users, and all sales data for them.

```
declare @samplerate int
set @samplerate = 50

select s.userID,
s.date,
s.SKU,
s.Campaign,
s.Device
from Sales s 
JOIN (select top(@samplerate) RAND() as rnd, x.userID
      from (select distinct userID 
            from Sales) x
      order by rnd) y
   on s.userID = y.userID
where s.date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @UserCount int
SET @UserCount = 50 --Set number of users

;WITH 
UserList AS --Get list of all unique users
(   SELECT DISTINCT UserID
    FROM Sales
),
RndList AS --Get list of # random users
(   SELECT TOP(@UserCount) UserID
    FROM UserList
    ORDER BY NewID()
)
--Get all Sales records for list of users
SELECT s.UserID,s.Date,s.SKU,s.Campaign,s.Device
FROM Sales s
JOIN RndList r ON r.userID = s.UserID
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31'
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I'm new to SQL so didn't know this is the workaround.  I spoke with one of my company's DBAs and we did a version of this solution.